# Handling html special chracter in django url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my django rest framework view:

```
class NewsArticleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = []
    serializer_class = NewsArticleSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.request.query_params.get('news', None)
        if slug:
            news = News.objects.filter(slug=slug)
            return news
        return []
```

which is working perfectly except when I pass html special chracter in url like this one:

```
?news=example/2020/4/4/&apos;53-lorem-ipsum&apos;
```

its returning nothing; because `self.request.query_params.get('news', None)` parsing as `example/2020/4/4/` not full string `example/2020/4/4/&apos;53-lorem-ipsum&apos;`

Here is value of `self.request.query_params` for debugging:

```
<QueryDict: {'news': ['example/2020/4/4/'], 'apos': ['', ''], '53-lorem-ipsum': ['']}>
```

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Django, "&" character is used to separate query string parameters in http requests. So when you have the "&" character in a parameter, server applications think that it is the start of the next parameter.

You need to encode your query string parameter before sending it to the server. The way to do it will change depending on the platform you're sending the request from, but on Javascript, you can use **encodeURIComponent** function.

```
encodeURIComponent('example/2020/4/4/&apos;53-lorem-ipsum&apos;')
```

returns "example%2F2020%2F4%2F4%2F%26apos%3B53-lorem-ipsum%26apos%3B"

Your Django app should be able to parse this as a single parameter then.